# Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux

I am trying to install linux headers for Kali 2017, but I am getting this error. What can I do about it? I have searched the whole internet (please don't think I have not), and there is no useful answer :(

```
~# apt-get install linux-header-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-header-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-header-4.9.0-kali4-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-header-4.9.0-kali4-amd64'
```

My repositories are:

```
    ~# leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list

 # deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

 #deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

 deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

 # For source package access, uncomment the following line
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Problem got solved! missing the 's' in headers! Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing an ‘s’, try

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

instead.

Comment: That's correct. It solved my problem. Sorry! I feel dumb now.

Comment: No worries, it happens ;-).